# How do i publish from Windows Calendar to Google Calendar?

Tags: windows-vista, google-calendar

How do i publish from Windows Calendar to Google Calendar? It would be nice to be able to publish to Google Apps Calendar as well.

Windows Calendar has a dialog for publishing a calendar and there is a text box for entering a location of the destination calendar. What URL would that be for a Google Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy to setup

1. Login to google calendar
2. goto settings
3. Click Calendars
4. Select the name of your calendar, probably your email address
5. Check out the private link section, you should be able to use this URL in windows calendar

Hope this helps